# How to print barcode Sticker with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular5

I am working on point of sale project with angular 6,
i need a way to print bar code label how can i do that?
Is there any library or any way to do that.

Comment: Try [JsBarcode](https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/). Closing this as Off-topic.

Comment: I don't want generate barcode i want to print barcode label